# capturing href with webdriver ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have the following html:

```
<a href="https://test.test.com/test/login.php?hash=c2e2ece406d1040d1a5c891fb625c38a370" target="_blank">Click this link</a>
```

I am having difficulty capturing the href link. I have tried:

```
    $hyperlink = @driver.find_element(:css, '#\3a gu > p:nth-child(5) > a')
    $hyperlink.attribute('class')
```

Which returns:

```
#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x56eec55201799a08 id="4">
```

I would like to parse the href link out of the html. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `#\3a gu > p:nth-child(5) > a` is the correct selector to return the intended element. If you want to get any attribute value then you should be passing `html attribute` name which in your case is `href`. You are passing the `class` attribute instead.

```
 $hyperlink = @driver.find_element(:css, '#\3a gu > p:nth-child(5) > a')
 $hyperlink.attribute('href')
```